# Spring boot fetch database data for multiple IDs using single call

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In spring boot project I have following code which cause low performance as several database calls happen inside a loop which is a bad practice.

```
userList.forEach(user -> {
     List<Project> userProjectsList = ProjectRepository.findByUser_UserIdOrderByDatecompletedDesc(user.getUserId());
}
```

**Note:** userList is a List returned from a stored procedure.
Project is an entity. Relevant repository for that entity is ProjectRepository.
User is also an entity.
Project and User entity has **many to one** relationship.

Project Entity is like below;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer projectid;
  private Calendar datecompleted;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "userid")
  private User user;

// getters and setters
}
```

I need to modify this code to be more efficient. As a solution I'm planning to fetch all projects belongs to all users **at once** from database. (Mysql database is using)

I tried with below code but seems it's not correct.

```
List<Integer> userIdList = UserList.stream().map(User::getUserId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<List<Project>> userProjectsList = ProjectRepository.findByUser_UserIdInOrderByDatecompletedDesc(userIdList);
```

Following method is in ProjectRepository.

```
List<List<Project>> findByUser_UserIdInOrderByDatecompletedDesc(List<Integer> userIdList);
```

Kindly support me to find a better solution for this. Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Above code is not returning the correct result. I passed 2 userIds. Out of them one user has 2 projects and the other user has 1 project.
Expected result is:

```
[0]->[0]:project1, [1]:project2
[1]->[0]:project3
```

But, returned result is:

```
[0]->[0]:project1
[1]->[0]:project2
[2]->[0]:project3
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing, is it not working or what, please explain?

Comment: I think you should first consider about your database design. I mean what is the relationship between users and projects. If it's a many to many relationship then you can create an intermediate table and change your query accordingly. Then you can select all projects of all users in just one step. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: @code_mechanic I updated the issue I'm facing.

Comment: @Onur Baştürk As I mentioned Project and User has Many to one relationship. Actually, in this stage I'm unable to change DB design.

Comment: @koko I think you cannot do such think using JPQL or QUERY per say, you want all the projects grouped by user and that too by passing userIds only, you would need to group the result yourself, because data will come in rows form, it won't create the group itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN` query for this. You need to declare you method signature as below:

```
findByNamesIn(Collection<String> names);
```

For more details and other queries, refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation